# Переключить фото в галерении

Tags: javascript, html, изображения

Делаю небольшую фото-галерею для карточки товара. Есть основное фото и несколько миниатюр. Нужно, чтобы при клике на миниатюру менялось основное фото. Я сделала следующее:

```js
const mainFoto = document.querySelector('.page-card__main');;
document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    if (e.target.closest('.page-card__img')) {
        mainFoto.src = e.target.src;
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="page-card__slider">
    <div class="page-card__image">
        <img class="page-card__main" src="./img/card-img/01.jpg" alt="main picture">                    
    <div class="page-card__preview">
        <img class="page-card__img" src="./img/card-img/01.jpg" alt="picture">
        <img class="page-card__img" src="./img/card-img/02.jpg" alt="picture">
        <img class="page-card__img" src="./img/card-img/03.jpg" alt="picture">
        <img class="page-card__img" src="./img/card-img/04.jpg" alt="picture">
        <img class="page-card__img" src="./img/card-img/05.jpg" alt="picture">
    </div>
</div>
```

Есть еще какие-то, более изящные, способы решить эту задачу? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Зачем вы меняете `src` у дива `.page-card__image`?

Comment: Это я случайно сюда написала, уже исправила

Comment: А почему вы решили, что это не работает на хостинге? Если изображения загружены, а код на своём месте, то всё должно работать.

Comment: @Юлия в коде вопроса ничего не исправлено. Да и подставьте абсолютные пути в пример, а не строки шаблонизатора.